# ASP.NET MVC ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess Imperative Calls and Unit Tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif

I've got code that uses CheckAccess with claims permission as so:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess("foo", "bar");
        return View();
    }
```

I have a unit test like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIndex()
    {

        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
        Assert.IsTrue(result.View != null);

    }
```

How do I mock ClaimsPrincipalPermission to always return successfully?  I know that i can move this code to an attribute which will solve the problem.  However, there are cases where I wish to call CheckAccess imperatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend wrapping this functionality into a dependency and using Dependancy Injection to make the code "Testable".

This involes "Extracting over overriding" this functionality into a different class and injecting the class into the controller.

By doing this removes your reliance on Static methods to an instance based method and will ensure you get a reliable result for testing purposes.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection